# Stop edit session with a NSTextField

Tags: ios

You can manually press 'Esc' key or click the `X` button at the right side to quit `NSTextField`'s editing mode.

So, how can I properly do it programmatically ?

```
/// those code is not working. 
_searchField.stringValue = @"";
if([_searchField abortEditing] )
{
}
[self.window endEditingFor:_searchField];
_searchField.editable = false;
_searchField.selectable=false;
[[_searchField window] makeFirstResponder:nil];
```

Though the focus is changed to the tableview , The little `x` button is still at the right side of textField ==> 
  [image: The little <code>x</code> button is still at the right side.]

Here is something i found : ["Stop edit session with a NSTextField"](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/230825-stop-edit-session-with-nstextfield.html).

It's there a better way doing this?

Comment: Just call resignFirstResponder on your text field.

Comment: resignFirstResponder is not working. @rdelmar

Comment: What does not working mean? The keyboard doesn't go away? Where are you calling resignFirstResponder?

Comment: The little x button is still at the right side. please see the picture .

Comment: I find a working solution.  Perform a selector with delay will be OK.     [window performSelector:@selector(makeFirstResponder:) withObject:otherView afterDelay:3];

Comment: This will working i found:  Setting the search field's stringValue to @"" in NSTextFieldDelegate's textShouldEndEditing method.